# Finding charge density from from differential form of Gauss law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law

[image]

I didn't get why he divided and multiplied by $r^2$. This question is from D J Griffith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is using spherical coordinates, and in spherical coordinates the divergence of a vector (like $\nabla\cdot \textbf{E}$) is:

$\nabla\cdot \textbf{A}=\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r^2 A_r \right) 
+ \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left(  A_\theta\sin\theta \right)
+ \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial A_\phi}{ \partial \phi}$

where $\textbf{A}=(A_r,A_\theta,A_\phi)$.

In your example we can ignore the angular components since the electric field is purely radial.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field given in the problem only depends on the radius $r$. Therefore, the divergence is most conveniently computed in spherical coordinates. The factors of $r^2$ and $1/r^2$ come from the transformation of $\nabla$ to spherical coordinates, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Spherical_coordinates). For a function $f(r)\hat{r}$ the divergence is 
$$\nabla\cdot f(r)\hat{r}=\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r{\left(r^2 f(r)\right)}.$$

Answer (score -1):

Look at the expression for the divergence in the spherical coordinates.